# How to update the video url...using jquery simple way?

Tags: jquery, video

I have this html..

```
<video id="task2ResultVideo" autobuffer poster="img/task2-results-host-poster.jpg">
   <source src="Video/webm/Task_2.4a_Host_treated.webm" type="video/webm" />
   <source src="Video/ogv/Task_2.4a_Host_treated.theora.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
   <source src="Video/MP4/Task_2.4a_Host_treated.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

In the page, some point, if the user click on the button i need to change the video according to the option what user clicked. (While user lick i generate the `task2Video[username]`, see below i declared.)

My video stock:

```
var task2Video = {
    jonkimpaulo : "Task_2.4a_Host_treated",
    jonpaulokim : "Task_2.4a_Host_treated",
    kimjonpaulo : "Task_2.5a_Host_treated",
    kimpaulojon : "Task_2.5a_Host_treated",
    paulokimjon : "Task_2.6a_Host_treated",
    paulojonkim : "Task_2.6a_Host_treated"
}
```

Using the above name, how can i replace all 3 types of format? Using like:

`task2Video[task2Video]`...like so?

Answer (score 0):

Assumming you want to keep particular file extensions, your script might look like:

```
// TODO implement yourself according to your needs
var nextvideo = task2Video.paulokimjon; 

// iterate thru all video sources
$('video source').each(function() {

    // remember the suffix
    var suffix = $(this).attr('src').split('.').pop();

    // update src (using new value, appending suffix)
    $(this).attr('src', nextvideo + '.' + suffix);

});
```

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WZ72Y/).

Comment: In the second source, there is 2 dot's in work... it makes issue. but thanks for you help

Comment: do you have any idea to handle this?

Comment: if it's the only case, you can add `if(suffix == 'ogv') suffix = 'theora.ogv';`